# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания? (1)

Tags: пунктуация

Любое использование материалов в частности, автоматизированное извлечение материалов платформы okhelps.com любыми сервисами запрещено.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Любое использование материалов, в частности автоматизированное извлечение материалов платформы okhelps.com любыми сервисами, запрещено.*

Уточнение, относящееся к "в частности", выделяется запятыми. После "в частности" запятая совсем не нужна.

Comment: А вот я не уверен, что здесь имеется в виду "извлечение сервисами", а не "использование сервисами". Вот, кстати, еще одна причина не заниматься выполнение "домашних заданий".  Пусть автор объяснит, чего ему надо и в чем сложность.

Comment: По смыслу все верно. Чтоб материал не копировали с сайта и не использовали его на других ресурсах. Поэтому "извлекать" им подходит слово)

Comment: Спасибо, Артём, за ответ

Comment: Не за что.) Behemothus имеет в виду, не такой ли смысл во фразе: *Любое использование материалов любыми сервисами, в частности автоматизированное извлечение материалов платформы okhelps.com, запрещено.* Если именно так правильно, тогда запятую я должен был поставить после адреса сайта. После Ваших объяснений я всё равно плохо понимаю, как правильно, уже всю голову сломал.))) Вообще странно, чтобы **сами** сервисы что-то использовали. А может, и нормально, тогда я просто не понимаю, что за сервисы такие.